# Center align the glyphicon in button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have reduced the width of the button and want to align the glyphicon in the center.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" style="width:20px">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

Here is a bootply link: http://www.bootply.com/HYU6Nff6bk#

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

The button still uses *padding-left: 10px;* and *padding-right: 10px;*

If you want to have a button with a width of 20px, then reduce padding-left and padding-right to zero.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" style="width:20px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
</div>
```